# php create array (dimensions/path) from different array-keys

Tags: php, arrays

I hope the title is not too bad. I'm not an english person and this would even be hard to put in one sentece in my mothertounge...

My problem is follwing:

Iwant to build a multidimensional array from a string like so:

```
$string = "a-b-c";
$val = "something";

$array['a']['b']['c'] = $val;
```

I tried some ideas of mine and ended up with a fried brain...
Hopefully you can help me! Thanks!

**EDIT** 
My approach:

```
 function recursion($c, $p, $v) {
        if (gettype($c) !== "array") $c = array();
        $c[$p] = $v;
        return $c;
    }

    foreach ($conf as $confLine) {
        $params = preg_split('/-/', $confLine->getParam());  //Here comes "a-b-c"
        $val = $confLine->getValue();  // The value 

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($params); $i++ ) {
            $galleryConfig = recursion($galleryConfig, $params[$i], $val);
        }
    }
```

**IMPORTANT**
I don't know how long the sting will be. If its a-b or a-b-c-d-e-f

Comment: Please post your ideas you tried.

Comment: `explode()` on - would be a start

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why do you need to do it this way?

Comment: Looking at the title are you suggesting that $string is actually an array, or is it a string as shown?

Comment: I agreed with @SamV. Why do you need to do this? This looks like a script with bad architecture. May be you can explain where did you get a-b-c-d strings from? May be it is easier to build an array of the string' source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$string = "a-b-c";
$val    = "something";

foreach (array_reverse(explode('-', $string)) as $key) {
    $val = array($key => $val);
}
```

or

```
$array = array_reduce(
    array_reverse(explode('-', $string)),
    function ($val, $key) { return array($key => $val); },
    $val
);
```

Comment: nice one. It's a little trickier than it appears on first sight. You beat me to it by a minute. :)

Comment: Nice function() i was looking for something like this. I hope it will fit in my program!